# Cannot install pyarrow from pip or conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, pyarrow

I am relatively new to package management and have hit a roadblock getting `pyarrow` to install in my Windows x64 machine.  Pyarrow docs say to use either

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyarrow
```

or

```
pip install pyarrow
```

https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/install.html

conda command gives

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
```

pip command gives a very lengthy error dump under the heading

```
Installing build dependencies ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

- I tried both in a Python 3.7.9 and a Python 3.8.5 conda environment
  since there is Github Jira discussion about this mattering at least
  historically (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-7076)
- On the conda approach, I [successfully] added https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64 to current channels, but still 'Package not found' for `pyarrow`. I did this out of confusion that my list of channels appearing to be 32-bit specific, and my machine is 64-bit
- There is ample evidence of pyarrow (2.0.0) presence in `Conda-forge/win-64`

Thanks for help in getting this package installed successfully.

This is the list of my current channels (with the 'win-64' one having been manually added) in the Conda 'Package not found' message

```
Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-32
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-32
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-32
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-32
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
```

Comment: It looks like you have installed 32 bit anaconda, even when you force it to use the 64 bit channel, it will not install packages from it. You will need to install the 64 bit anaconda (or miniconda). For the pip approach, please add the full error to your question

Comment: Thanks FlyingTeller.  That makes sense.  I posted an initial chunk of the error (but the whole thing greatly exceeds StackOverflow limits)

Comment: Adding a corrected comment now that issue is solved...Followup on FlyingTeller comment for others like me who may not have been well-informed about 32/64 bit Python topic. My Windows Python is in fact Anaconda-installed and us the 32-bit version (my "hardware" is 64-bit Parallels VM). The following two lines of code return either '32' or '64' as a check. `import struct`   `struct.calcsize("P") * 8`

Answer (score 1):

Will answer my own question: Arrow does not support 32-bit per per xhochy's response [in this thread](https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/6902), so my 32-bit Anaconda Navigator running on my 64-bit hardware was the issue. I will work on getting knowledgeable enough to submit Pull Request to add to Apache documentation because it would have kept someone like me from being battered by this issue.

**Solution for getting pyarrow installed in Windows**
(Can also do from command line, but I'm working with consulting client who is based in Anaconda Navigator):

- If running 32-bit Anaconda Navigator, uninstall it [per their instructions](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/) Additional detail to their docs are that mentioned `envs` and `pkgs` subdirectories are typically at `c:\users\username\anaconda3`. First, throw these in the trash.  Then uninstall Anaconda 32-bit using Add/Remove Programs in Windows as they instruct
- Install 64-bit Anaconda from latest installer on their website
- Open Anaconda Navigator and click on **Environment**
- (to install for **base(root)** environment which will be default after fresh install of Navigator) choose **Not Installed** and click **Update Index**... button
- pyarrow should show up in the updated list of available packages.
- Click the Apply button and let it install

That's it to get pyarrow installed to be able to work with .feather format files in Windows Python

I did not test this directly in Conda (outside of Anaconda Navigator), but I presume [that the Conda command line install instruction in Apache documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/install.html) works just fine if one is starting with 64-bit Python on their Windows machine.  Also will mention that Mac OS X Python is apparently 64-bit by default, so this thread addresses a Windows-specific watchout.

Comment: Really, in general there's no reason to use a 32-bit Anaconda, which will come with memory limitations and will probably in many cases be slightly slower too. I assume you're using Anaconda for data analysis, so you certainly want the much expanded memory support that a 64-bit install brings.

Comment: Yes.  You make a good point.  I learned something from the experience.  In my defense, the two versions sit side by side on the Anaconda install page without guidance for the user on how to choose.  When I did the install (a while ago), I'm sure my internal thought process was that 32 bit has been around longer, so it's safe.

Answer (score 0):

Before install pyarrow, you need to install dependency in this page: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145. Besides, if you have the installation of visual studio,you may have the packges like vc_redist-2015-2019, delete it to make sure you can install these two packages.